# yii2 Pjax and GridView (pagination and post request)

Tags: yii2

As I understood when I click on the button "Confirm" pjax reload widget with new data,and started with firs paging page.
1)Is there any way to load new data but stay at current paging page?
2)Is there any way to sent 'id' parameter by POST method?

Controller

```
 public function actionIndex()
        {
                 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => Orders::find()->with('orderServices.services','orderEmployees','user'),
                'pagination' =>['pageSize' => 3],
            ]);


            return $this->render('index', [
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
        }
```

In View

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
// ... configuration here

            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{update} {delete} {approve}'
                ,
            'buttons' => [
                'approve' => function ($url,$model,$key) {
                    if($model->status=='not confirm')
                    {
                        return Html::a('Confirm',Url::toRoute(['controller/action', 'id' => $model->id]));/// має бути Ajax
                    }

                },
            ],
        ]
]);
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't if this could be useful for you but with :

```
 Yii::$app->request->get('page')
```

You can obtain the current GET page in this way and use for your need